# Can not flatten a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, flatten

Why isn't flatten working? I have looked at example code and I am doing exactly what they are doing in the example. I've even copied their code and ran it but the array still doesn't come out as a flattened array.
I don't know if it matters but I am running Python 3.7.4.

code:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 8], [9, 5, 1, 7, 5, 3]])
array1.flatten()
print(array1)
```

output:

```
[[1 2 3 2 5 8]
 [9 5 1 7 5 3]]
```

desired output:

```
[1 2 3 2 5 8 9 5 1 7 5 3]
```

Comment: The example code probably displays `array1.flatten()` itself (with a print or interactive display).  You are printing `array1` separately.  If that isn't clear you many need to copy-n-paste the example, or provide a link.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, it's a trivial issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array1.flatten()` returns the flattened array but does not change in place. Try equating it back should work.
Code:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 8], [9, 5, 1, 7, 5, 3]])
array1 = array1.flatten()
print(array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the `array1.flatten()` to a variable, so something like this could work `array2 = array1.flatten()`.